# Isotypic components with respect to a subgroup

Tags: representation-theory

In a book I'm currently reading, the author assumes some knowledge in representation theory that I think I lack and couldn't find.

We are dealing with a group $G$ and a (possibly infinite dimensional) unitary representation $(\pi,H)$. We have a finite subgroup $K<G$.

What is the "$K$-isotypic decomposition" of $H$ (into a finite direct sum)?

I'm fairly familiar with the decomposition into $\lambda$-isotypic components, for $\lambda$ a highest-weight, but I couldn't make sense of the above phrase. Is it a decomposition into $K$-invariant minimal subspaces? If so, why does one exist? (In other words, is it equivalent to the isotypic decomposition I know?)

What I can see is that the representation can be restricted to $K$ and still be unitary representation (this time of a finite group), and we can decompose into (a finite number, correct?) of isotypic components. Are those actually invariant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By restriction, $H$ is a representation of the finite group $K$.
The group $K$ has a finite number of isomorphism classes of
irreducible representations $\rho_1,\ldots,\rho_k$. For each $\rho_j$
consider $H_j$, the sum of all $K$-submodules of $H$ isomorphic to
$\rho_i$. The $H_i$ are the $K$-isotypic components of $H$: $H$
is the direct sum of the $H_i$.

Comment: Thanks you very much, that's what I thought. What can be said about the relation of these components and the subgroup $K$, especially regarding invariance?

Comment: The way I understand it, each component is still irreducible in the sense that there is no subspace which is closed under the action of $K$. Is it true?

Comment: @Thewayoflife No, isotypical components are typically (highly) reducible, as they decompose (non uniquely) into many copies of the same representation. As an extreme case, if the irreducible of $K$ is $1$-dimensional, then _any_ subspace of the isotypical component (which could be infinite dimensional) will be $K$-stable.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see. Then what is the interest in looking at those components? What I'm trying to understand is what makes them different from any decomposition of $H$ into a finite sum.

Are they of significance in particular when $K$ satisfies some condition? (such as central which might be relevant to the text I'm reading, but also any other condition?)

Comment: The interest is that it is a decomposition into $K$-stable subspaces that is _canonically_ determined by the $K$-action, and it is the finest such decomposition. Compare it with a decomposition into eigenspaces for a single operator; eigenspaces are not irreducible as soon as their dimension exceeds$~1$,  but no finer decomposition is defined by the operator itself.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Do you have a reference for the facts discussed here?

Comment: @CountOlenski: No I don't recall which books I consulted 3 years ago, but my guess would be none. Just look up the definition of isotypical component in your favourite go-to resource.